# Is this sort an insertion sort?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, iterator, doubly-linked-list

So I have tried to make an insertion sort for doubly linked list with iterators. It returns a sorted list with the 'keys' sorted from smaller to bigger. Althought my code doesn't sort the actual list and i am not sure if it's an insertion sort. Can anyone help?

```
public static List sort(List list) {        
        List sortedList = new List();                  // sortedList
        List.Iter curIndex = List.Iter.last(sortedList);  // terminated forward iterator        
                
        for(List.Iter iter = List.Iter.first(list); !iter.end(); iter.next()) {
            curIndex = List.Iter.last(sortedList);
            List.Node node = iter.key_data();  
            System.out.println("node: "+node.data);
            System.out.println("curIndex: "+curIndex.key_data().data);
            if (sortedList.empty()) {                
                sortedList.insAfter(curIndex, node.key, node.data);                
            }
            else if (curIndex.key_data().key >= node.key) {
                boolean hasPrev = true;
                while (hasPrev && curIndex.key_data().key >= node.key) {
                    hasPrev = curIndex.prev();                    
                }                                
                sortedList.insAfter(curIndex, node.key, node.data);                        
            }
            else {                            
                boolean hasNext = true;
                while (hasNext && curIndex.key_data().key < node.key) {
                    hasNext = curIndex.next();
                }
                sortedList.insAfter(curIndex, node.key, node.data);                
            }
            
        }
        return sortedList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not the definition of *insertion sort* would still consider your code to be an implementation of that, is probably a matter of interpretation. But in the more strict definition of *insertion sort*, the algorithm should *move* nodes, not create new nodes. This is what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Algorithm) has as definition:

> Insertion sort iterates, consuming one input element each repetition, and grows a sorted output list. At each iteration, insertion sort **removes** one element from the input data, finds the location it belongs within the sorted list, and inserts it there.

I highlight the word **removes**, which is an action your algorithm does not perform. The same article has a section specifically on linked lists, where it [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#List_insertion_sort_code_in_C) (my highlights):

> If the items are stored in a linked list, then the list can be sorted with **O(1) additional space**. The algorithm starts with an initially empty (and therefore trivially sorted) list. The input items are **taken off** the list one at a time, and then inserted in the proper place in the sorted list. When the input list is empty, the sorted list has the desired result.

Your implementation needs O(n) space. It would be more in line with the spirit of *insertion sort*, if it would do as described in that quote: instead of creating new nodes, it could *take* the original node object out of the original list, and *rewire* it so it becomes part of the newly sorted list, such that the whole process does not ever create new nodes.

Comment: So can I not use insAfter? Also how could I do what you said (taking the original node and rewiring it without creating new node)?

Comment: I'm not saying you should change anything. You get a sorted list, so you can just stick with it. Only if you want to abide by a more strict **interpretation** of insertion sort, you may want to avoid creating new nodes. If you go for that you cannot use `insAfter`, as that evidently has logic in it that creates a new node. If you have a problem in implementing it in a way without creating new nodes, then please ask a new question about it, showing your attempt and where you got stuck.

Comment: NB: if you are also the owner of the code that **creates** the list, it is easier to keep the list sorted from the start, and only allow nodes to be inserted via one method -- which you could call `insertSorted`, which finds the right insertion spot based on order, and then creates and inserts the node at that spot. Then your list is always sorted.

Comment: I am the owner of the code but I have been instructed to write it this way. So I will make a new question like you told me (where I show my code).